# Weird errors -607/-11003 when retrieving BYTE-values

Tags: informix

We have some very simple `(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data BYTE)`-tables that I'm trying to retrieve the data from, but seem to run into some kind of data corruption. When accessing or retrieving the `data`-column e.g. via `SELECT data FROM foobar WHERE id = 42` or `SELECT LENGTH(data) FROM foo WHERE id = 42` I get

```
[HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Text/Byte subscript error. (-607) (SQLFetch)
```

which is obviously weird, as no byte subscript operator is used. It rather seems to me Informix is running into some kind of data corruption issue and is unable to retrieve the underlying BLOB. The query works if I explicitly exclude the offending row, so `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(data)) FROM foo` fails with the above error, while `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(data)) FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (42,...)` succeeds.

For other rows, I retrieve an error

```
[01004] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Data truncated. (-11003) (SQLGetData)
```

which also can only be mitigated by (finding and) excluding the offending row via their primary key.

First of all, is there a way to tell if this is a driver/odbc error or if the underlying data is actually corrupted? Is there a way to check the tables for data corruption, instead of running into this kind of problem one by one?

This is `IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC5WE`

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like running the same query, but using different tool or method, would give you an idea if it's the driver or the data itself.

If the data is corrupted, you can use the following to confirm the checksum value and identify:

```
CHECKSUM TABLE foobar;
```

Also, obviously updating the driver version is given, have you tried that?

Comment: `informix` does not support the `CHECKSUM TABLE` statement, to the best of my knowledge